# Como fazer deploy sem alterar o conteúdo de uma pasta no servidor?

Tags: git, node.js

Sou novo no mundo NodeJs e Git, estou tentando desenvolver do um sistema onde os usuários fazem upload de imagens.

Toda vez que faço **deploy** do app, as imagens dos usuários são excluídas da pasta **public/uploads/**

Como devo proceder para que os arquivos das pessoas não sejam excluídos neste caso caso?
Tentei usar .gitignore na pasta de uploads, mas não adiantou.

Pensei em hospedar as imagens em um servidor separado do server onde está o app, mas só se não tiver outro jeito mesmo.

Preciso de uma maneira de manter a pasta **public/uploads/** sem ser alterada quando fizer algum deploy.

Obs.: O site é em NodeJs. O deploy é feito usando Git no servidor Openshift.

Comment: Está gravando as imagens dentro do diretório de sua aplicação? É claro que se fizer um deploy elas irão sumir, porque está sobreescrevendo. Para resolver, tente usar um diretório fora de sua aplicação, por exemplo: `/var/uploads`, etc...

Comment: OK, resolvido! No OpenShift, tem um espaço própro para armazenamento de arquivos /app-root/data/ . Dá pra acessá-lo via sftp pelo filezilla.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150714/upload-file-on-openshift
Valeu, Wakim; Caputo!

Comment: Essa informação é bem interessante. Poderia incluir uma resposta e aceitá-la, para que outros que venham através dessa pergunta conheçam essa solução.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

A pasta de upload deve ser removida do repositório e inserida no .gitignore (o git ignore não funciona se o arquivo já está no repositório)

```
public/uploads/*
```

Depois de remover vc cria um arquivo vazio (eu normalmente chamo ele de empty). Este arquivo deve ser inserido forcadamente no repositório.

```
git add -f public/uploads/empty
```

Com isso somente este arquivo na pasta sera trackeado. O git criará a pasta porém não vai mexer nos arquivos que estiverem no servidor.